# can't detect equal sign on image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, detection

[image]

I'm working on a computer vision project that understands mathematical signs. It detects all correctly except the "Equal" mark. But the "equal" sign is perceived as two separate "minus" signs.

```py
    image = cv2.imread('./deneme.png')
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(image.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(grey.copy(), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    preprocessed_digits = []
    for c in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
        digit = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        digit = make_square(digit)
        preprocessed_digits.append(digit)
    plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
    plt.show()
```

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this problem. How can I detect the equal sign?

Comment: if you can assume that your formula is written horizontal, you can try to estimate the maximum height of all symbols and vertically group symbols which are too close to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that the result you're trying to achieve?

[image]

Since it seems that your math expressions are written horizontally, as @Micka points out, you have very strong priors on the relationship between the two different components of an equal sign, so there is a straight-forward (but hacky) way to detect when to minus signs are actually an equal:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Rect:
    def __init__(self,
            a,
            b,
            c,
            d):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
        self.d=d

        self.center=np.array([(a+c)/2, (b+d)/2])

def merge_rectangles(r_1, r_2):

    a_m= min(r_1.a, r_2.a)
    b_m= min(r_1.b, r_2.b)
    c_M= max(r_1.c, r_2.c)
    d_M= max(r_1.d, r_2.d)

    return Rect(a_m, b_m, c_M, d_M)

def they_form_an_equal_sign(rect_1,
        rect_2,
        tol_w=10,#in pixels
        tol_h=10):
    #check if the bounding boxes approximately align
    b0 = (np.abs(rect_1.a - rect_2.a) < tol_w ) and (np.abs(rect_1.c - rect_2.c) <     tol_w)

    #check if the bounding boxes have approximately the same height
    h1 = np.abs(rect_1.d - rect_1.b)
    h2 = np.abs(rect_2.d - rect_2.b)
    b1 = np.abs(h1-h2) < tol_h

    return b0 and b1

image = cv2.imread('/tmp/m.png')
grey = cv2.cvtColor(image.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(grey.copy(), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,     cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

candidate_rectangles=[]
for c in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    candidate_rectangles.append(Rect(x,y,x+w,y+h))

kept=np.ones(len(candidate_rectangles))
new_rectangles=[]
for i in range(len(candidate_rectangles)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(candidate_rectangles)):
        b=they_form_an_equal_sign(candidate_rectangles[i], candidate_rectangles[j])
        if b:
            new_rect=merge_rectangles(candidate_rectangles[i], candidate_rectangles[j])
            new_rectangles.append(new_rect)
            kept[i]=0
            kept[j]=0

for i in range(len(kept)):
    if kept[i]:
        rect=candidate_rectangles[i]
        cv2.rectangle(image, (rect.a, rect.b), (rect.c, rect.d), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
for rect in new_rectangles:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (rect.a, rect.b), (rect.c, rect.d), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)

plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray") 
plt.show()
```

Basically, this takes the brute-force approach of comparing every two bounding boxes that have been detected in your code, and merging them into a larger one if they meet the requirements from your prior: *i.e.* if they are horizontally algined (as the top and bottom parts of a minus sign should) and if their height is approximately the same.

However, this is obviously not robust: you need to adjust thresholds and the entire thing will fall apart if your expressions aren't horizontal and clearly separated. If you want a more robust/useful system, basic ML approaches for character recognition are a better place to start.